# Como pegar o resultado de um JSON onde o resultado é HTML e na View do Ionic renderizar o HTML?

Tags: javascript, html5, json, ionic2, ionic3

Tenho um JSON onde o conteúdo de alguns campos são HTML, gostaria de apresentar o HTML na View do Ionic já renderizado.

Este é o JSON:

```
[{"data":"2018-09-05","categoria":"1","desafio":"
\r\n
Burp 20x1<\/li>\r\n
Teste 30x4<\/li>\r\n
Variação 50x10<\/li>\r\n<\/ul>\r\n
Competição<\/strong><\/p>\r\n

\r\n
Luta livre<\/li>\r\n
Burp<\/li>\r\n<\/ul>","titulo":"Desafio do Dia"}]
```

O campo "desafio" é que está em HTML, **como renderizar o HTML na View?**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="dark">
    <ion-title text-center>Workout do Dia</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <div class="container">
    <ul *ngFor="let workout of workoutdetalhes">
      <li><span></span>
        <div>
          <div class="title">{{workout.titulo}}</div>
          <div class="info">{{workout.desafio}}</div>          
        </div> 
      </li>    
    </ul>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div [innerHTML]="workout"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado @Hitmacreed não estava sabendo era como colocar, deu certo: <ion-card-content [innerHTML]="workout.desafio">
              {{workout.desafio}}
          </ion-card-content> Obrigado.

Comment: @Hitmacreed, recomenda-se que detalhe um pouco mais a sua resposta, explicando, no geral, o que faz.

Comment: Seria interessante que você detalhasse um pouco sua resposta, explicando porque o @Ramos deveria utilizar essa parte em seu código.